# Iterate through optional vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, option-type

I have an optional vector like `optional<std::vector<string>> vec = {"aa", "bb"};`

How can I iterate through the vector?

Doing the following:

```
for (string v : vec) {
    cout<<v<<endl;
}
```

gives the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::optional<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)’
     for (string v : vec) {
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I iterate though the optional vector?

Comment: Not calling the `optional` "`vec`" might help reducing the confusion, because it isn't. ;-)

Comment: @user17732522 That's true. I too gave the answer for `std::optional`.

Comment: `isf` is another namespace I was using in my code

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] to prevent confusion.

Comment: We can just assume for the sake of this question that we are using `std::optional`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [dereference operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) on `vec`.

```
for (string v : *vec) {
    cout<<v<<endl;
}
```

Note that your program will exhibit undefined behavior with this if `vec.has_value() == false`. So... check for that first.

Answer (score 3):

The below code works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    std::optional<std::vector<std::string>> vec({ "aa", "bb" });

    if (vec.has_value()) // If vec has a value
    {
        for (auto& v : vec.value()) 
        {
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here in the above code, I am iterating through the elements of the `vector` by using `vec.value()`.

Comment: Everyone here is giving solutions for `std::optional`. You should mention it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution where not the implicit iterator of the for-loop is used, but an std::iterator. In this case, the trick with getting the value first solves the problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

struct myStruct {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 6;
};
using OptmyStruct = std::optional<myStruct>;

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<OptmyStruct> myVec = {myStruct{}, myStruct{42,42}};
    std::vector<OptmyStruct>::iterator myIt = myVec.begin();
    myIt->value().a;
}
```